# pikaday plugin 15 day between two date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, date-range, pikaday

I have a booking form and I need just two input `.checkin` and `.checkout` and that is why I have used `datepicker` with `daterange` everything is going ok almost one thing is how can I choose just 15 day between two date ?

by the way I'm using [pikaday plugin](https://github.com/dbushell/Pikaday)
MY CODE

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.checkin, .checkout', function (){
    return new Pikaday({
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   field: this,
   format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
   minDate: new Date(),
   firstDay: 1,
   maxDate: new Date(2020, 12, 31),
   onSelect: function() {
    e = this.getDate();
   }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form">
<input type="text" class="checkin" placeholder="Checkin" />
<input type="text" class="checkout" placeholder="Checkout" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the `minDate` & `maxDate` of checkout datepicker based on the value of checkin datepicker.

I have used `getMaxDate()` to get the max date for datepicker & if it is checkout picker, i am setting the `maxdate` as 15 + checkin date.
Similarly i have use `getMinDate()` to get min date for datepicker & if it is checkout picker, i am setting the `mindate` as checkin date.

```js
$(document).on('focus', '.checkin, .checkout', function (){
    return new Pikaday({
   numberOfMonths: 2,
   field: this,
   format: "DD.MM.YYYY",
   minDate: getMinDate(this),
   firstDay: 1,
   maxDate: getMaxDate(this),
   onSelect: function() {
    e = this.getDate();
   }
  });
});
function getMaxDate(element){
  if(element.className=='checkout' && element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value)
    return new Date(new Date(element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value).getTime()+(15*24*60*60*1000));
else
  return new Date(2020, 12, 31);
  }
function getMinDate(element){
  if(element.className=='checkout' && element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value)
    return new Date(element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').value);
  else
  return new Date();
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/pikaday.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pikaday/1.5.1/css/pikaday.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="form">
<input type="text" class="checkin" placeholder="Checkin" />
<input type="text" class="checkout" placeholder="Checkout" />
</div>
```

Comment: hi great answer and solution thank for it.I have couple of question for example I don't want to use `.checkin` and `.checkout` classes..I want to use ID instead of class for example ``#checkin` and `checkout` and how can I change it className ? I tried getElementByID but nothing change

Comment: Use `id` instead of `className` and inside `querySelector` it will be `#checkin`

Comment: hi I try to do that but it won't wokr how can I apply it for id?

Comment: do I have to remove `element.parentNode.querySelector('.checkin').` because I won't using `.checkin` or `.checkout` classes how do I replace my codes ?

Comment: Yes , you need to remove it and add `element.parentNode.querySelector('#checkin')` there.